# Need facebook data via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I am using a C# facebook application, I can able to get list of users (with their Id)who liked and comment for videos by passing the corresponding video id.
Now, I need the below details using the same application.

- Friends name,
- Views,
- no of friends,  groups,
- no videos,
- Date joined,
- no of video unlikes,
- no of comments unlikes,

Please let me know if there is a way to get these details….Waiting for your reply..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of waiting you can just check how to do it yourself using the Facebook API documentation.

Comment: I have tried them using all possible ways using the documentation. Either these fields is not supported or it is not in API doc itself. I am just curious to hear from this forum whether any of them have faced the similar roadblocks so that i can come into a conclusion whether this can be done or not.

Answer (score 0):

If a user has not authorized your application, you can get very limited information about them. Of the list you posted you can only get their name.